# Type narrowing with generic object type unions

Tags: typescript

The following types are used in an event system for object changes.

I'm having troubles with narrowing an object type based on certain conditions. For example, when the `prop` property is null, we know for sure that `deleted` will be false.

The failing cases are demonstrated below: [(playground link)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20const%20change%3A%20Change%3C%7B%20a%3A%20number%3B%20b%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(change.prop%20%3D%3D%3D%20'a')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20change.prop%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20change.newValue%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20%22number%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(change.prop%20%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20change.prop%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20%22null%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20change.deleted%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20%22false%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20change.newValue%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20%22%7Ba%3A%20number%3B%20b%3A%20string%7D%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Change%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20RootChange%3CT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20(T%20extends%20object%20%3F%20NestedChange%3CT%3E%20%3A%20never)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RootChange%3CT%3E%20%3D%20IChange%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20oldValue%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newValue%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20deleted%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NestedChange%3CT%20extends%20object%20%3D%20any%2C%20P%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3D%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20(IChange%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20P%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oldValue%3A%20T%5BP%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newValue%3A%20T%5BP%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20deleted%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20(IChange%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20P%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oldValue%3A%20T%5BP%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newValue%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20deleted%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IChange%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20property%20being%20changed.%20When%20null%2C%20this%20change%20is%20for%20the%20root%20value.%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20keyof%20any%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20previous%20value%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20oldValue%3A%20unknown%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20next%20value%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newValue%3A%20unknown%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20Whether%20the%20property%20has%20been%20deleted%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20deleted%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D)

```
declare const change: Change<{ a: number; b: string }>

if (change.prop === 'a') {
    change.prop // OK
    change.newValue // Expected to be "number"
}

if (change.prop == null) {
    change.prop // Expected to be "null"
    change.deleted // Expected to be "false"
    change.newValue // Expected to be "{a: number; b: string}"
}

type Change<T = any> =
    | RootChange<T>
    | (T extends object ? NestedChange<T> : never)

type RootChange<T> = IChange & {
    prop: null
    oldValue: T
    newValue: T
    deleted: false
}

type NestedChange<T extends object = any, P extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    | (IChange & {
        prop: P
        oldValue: T[P]
        newValue: T[P]
        deleted: false
    })
    | (IChange & {
        prop: P
        oldValue: T[P]
        newValue: undefined
        deleted: true
    })

interface IChange {
    /** The property being changed. When null, this change is for the root value. */
    prop: keyof any | null
    /** The previous value */
    oldValue: unknown
    /** The next value */
    newValue: unknown
    /** Whether the property has been deleted */
    deleted: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with `NestedChange`. The way you defined the type for `{a: number, b: string}` it is equivalent to:

```
type NestedChange<{a: number, b: string}> =
    | (IChange & {
        prop: "a" | "b"
        newValue: number | string
        deleted: false
    })
    | (IChange & {
        prop: "a" | "b"
        newValue: undefined
        deleted: true
    })
```

So there is no relation between the property type and the property name, `prop:"a"` can be paired with a `string` as far as the compiler is concerned.

You want a union that looks more like this:

```
 { prop: "a"; newValue: number; deleted: false; } | 
 { prop: "a"; newValue: undefined; deleted: true; } | 
 { prop: "b"; newValue: string; deleted: false; } | 
 { prop: "b"; newValue: undefined; deleted: true; }
```

You can create such a union using the distributive behavior of union types (read [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)). This means that if we have a naked type parameter that contains a union of the keys of `T` we can iterate over the keys and apply the type transformation on each key and get out a union containing the transformation applied to each key.

To introduce the new type parameter and distribute over it we use two conditional types :`keyof T extends infer P ? P extends any ? ... : never: never`. In neither type is the condition important, we use the first conditional (`keyof T extends infer P`) to introduce a new type parameter `P`, and we use the second conditional (`P extends any` ) to trigger the distributive behavior.

```
declare const change: Change<{ a: number; b: string }>

if (change.prop === 'a') {
    change.prop // OK
    change.newValue // is number | undefined
    if (change.deleted) {
        change.newValue // undefined
    } else {
        change.newValue // number
    }
}

if (change.prop == null) {
    change.prop // is "null"
    change.deleted // is "false"
    change.newValue // is "{a: number; b: string}"
}

type Change<T = any> =
    | RootChange<T>
    | (T extends object ? NestedChange<T> : never)

type RootChange<T> = IChange & {
    prop: null
    newValue: T
    deleted: false
}

type NestedChange<T extends object> = keyof T extends infer P ?
    P extends any ?
    (IChange & {
        prop: P
        newValue: T[P]
        deleted: false
    })
    | (IChange & {
        prop: P
        newValue: undefined
        deleted: true
    })
    : never : never;
interface IChange {
    /** The property being changed. When null, this change is for the root value. */
    prop: keyof any | null
    /** The previous value */
    oldValue: unknown
    /** The next value */
    newValue: unknown
    /** Whether the property has been deleted */
    deleted: boolean
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've never seen `keyof T extends infer P` before. Very interesting.

Comment: @aleclarson hope it helps, let me know if I can help with anything :)

Comment: @aleclarson the solution works in the playground but strict null checks are required, as you use `prop: null` for root changes

Comment: I always forget to enable that in playgrounds! Should be the default. Thanks :P